# Phrasal verb "zonk out"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> I **zonked out** and I couldn't go to work.

Does this mean he fall down and hurt himself?

Comment: Beware that questions answerable using a dictionary are in danger of being closed on this site. If dictionaries failed to provide a fitting description, it's better to explain why, for instance by providing more context.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning, its usage and examples are given [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/zonk+out). Go through it. Its pretty self explanatory. If you still don't get it, ELL will surely help you with it. But make sure you google out for plausible solutions before asking it here. If you still find it hard to follow, there are many people who could help you here.

> **zonk out:** a state of fatigue, due to which a person may fall asleep quickly, or may look tired and worn-out. A lesser extreme variation of *'passing out'*.